# Как сложить все числа в строке?

Tags: java, scanner

Как вывести сумму чисел в строке? 
Например: qwe120sd33d03 => 120+33+03 = sum 156. И тому подобное...
Вот с однозначными числами проблемы нет, а с многозначными сложнее. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: а покажите, как у вас организовано с однозначным числом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение без регулярных выражений, в лоб:

```
String str = "sdfa3214adsf41agsd";
int sizeOfStr = str.length();
int sum = 0;
int tempNum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<sizeOfStr; ++i){
  if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))){
    tempNum = (10 * tempNum) + Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i));
  } else {
    sum += tempNum;
    tempNum = 0;
  }
}
sum+=tempNum;
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: @vp_arth, да, точно

Answer (score 2):

Можно регулярными выражениями:

```
import java.util.regex.*;


String s = "qwe120sd33d03";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
Integer sum = 0;
while (m.find()) {
  sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
}
System.out.printf("%d\n", sum);
```